# Rounding down with Parsefloat

Tags: jquery

I've got a function that divides a number (in this case, 2500), by 24. In this case, it is 104.166666 repeating, and when I calculate it to 2 places, i get 104.17 (which is correct). However, how can I make it round to 104.16 instead (rounding down)?

```
var sum = parseFloat(val1) * parseFloat(val2); //here sum is = to 104.1666666
    if (isNaN(sum)) { 
        sum = 0;
    }
    total.val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2)); // here it becomes 104.17, but I want it to round down instead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this, by multiplying by 100, you get your desired precision, floor that down, and divide by 100 to put the decimal places back where they belong :)

```
parseFloat(Math.floor(sum * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
```